# Converting from Double to Binary

Tags: java, floating-point, binary, hex, octal

I've been a lot of trouble figuring this class problem. My due date is tomorrow and I still don't know how to do it. I made a code when the input put by the user is converted into binary, octal, and hexadecimal. Now, the problem is that now they are asking me to modify the code in a way that the user inputs a Double or Floating point and convert it into decimal. My greatest problem is working with the decimal numbers; for example, 5**.987**. I will leave the code I already created. I would be very grateful is someone could help! thanks :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class EncodingTester {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    byte largestPositiveByte   = 127;
    short largestPositiveShort = 32767;
    int largestPositiveInt     = 2147483647;
    long largestPositiveLong   = 9223372036854775807L;
    long largestPositiveLongPlusOne   = 9223372036854775807L;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Next number (0 to stop): ");
    long nextNumber = in.nextLong();

    while (nextNumber != 0) {

        int radix;


        double logBase2 = Math.log(nextNumber) / Math.log(2);

        double absoluteNumOfBits = 1 + Math.floor(logBase2);

        double maxBits = Math.max(8, absoluteNumOfBits);

        double numBits = Math.log(maxBits) / Math.log(2);

        int newNumBits = (int) Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(numBits));

        System.out.println("The absolute number of bits is:  " +absoluteNumOfBits +". The final number of bits is: " +newNumBits +".");

        radix = 10;
        System.out.println("Decimal: " + String.format("%s",  Double.toString(nextNumber)).replace(' ','0'));

        radix = 2;
        System.out.println("Binary: " + String.format("%"+newNumBits+"s",  Long.toString(nextNumber,radix)).replace(' ','0'));

        radix = 8;
        System.out.println("Octal: " + String.format("%"+((int) Math.ceil(newNumBits/3.0))+"s",  Long.toString(nextNumber,radix)).replace(' ','0'));

        radix = 16;
        System.out.println("Hexadecimal: 0x" + String.format("%"+newNumBits/4+"s",  Long.toString(nextNumber,radix)).replace(' ','0'));

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Next number: (0 to stop)");
        nextNumber = in.nextLong();
    }
    System.out.println("Good Bye");
 }
}
```

Comment: a `double` has 64bits and you can get the bit representation via `Double.doubleToLongBits(1.234)`

Comment: So, I would have to initialize it to a variable of type long? thankz! :)

Comment: I don't really understand what you try to do here :) Maybe. There are btw constants like `Long.MAX_VALUE`, `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, .. that have those max positive values. `largestPositiveLongPlusOne` is actually the max for long and you can't represent the number that is one greater than that.

Comment: The problem is that I put long newNextDouble = Double.doubleToLongBits(nextNumber) and I use newNextDouble wherever I had the nextNumber. But the program doesnt like it :( I dont understand why myself :/

Comment: Double.doubleToLongBits should actually work, what do you want to do with this bits? do you want to convert only the integer part? Could you give an example on what do you get and what should be your output?

Comment: Okay, well the user should input a floating point or Double type number. And then we have to make the program system.out the result: its conversion into binary, hexadecimal and octal. For example if I input 2.25 for the binary part the result should be 10.01. When I use Double.doubleToLongBits(), im getting a buch of 0's and 1's plus the program is telling me that there are obsolete methods :/

Comment: The long bits version is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format - yours seems to be similar but I guess you'll have to calculate those on your own.